# Getting docker-compose TypeError: kwargs_from_env() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ssl_version' in GitLab

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, cicd

I'm using GitLab CICD, in docker-test stage as defined
`docker_test: image: docker:stable services: - docker:stable-dind stage: docker-test`
...

yesterday worked fine, but today - GitLab pipeline 'docker_test' fails with:
TypeError: kwargs_from_env() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ssl_version'

I've found on the internet that it could be an upgrade to 7.0.0
https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/change-log.html

Someone here suggested (for a different setup) downgrading to prev 6.3.1

After searching - have no idea how to do that.
Maybe there are other solutions to this?

Answer (score 38):

Summarising the discussion at [docker-py](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/3194):

Docker<sup>1</sup> has made a [change](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/releases/tag/7.0.0) in v7.0.0 that breaks Docker Compose v1 written in Python (`pip install docker-compose` available as `docker-compose`). It has been deprecated and replaced by Docker Compose v2 implemented in Go, which comes OOB as `docker compose` (sub-command).

Permanent fix: Switch to Docker Compose v2 (no extra installation required, read the [migration docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/migrate) to fix compatibility issues).

Temporary fix: Downgrade Docker<sup>1</sup> using `pip install docker==6.1.3` to the version that works with Docker Compose (v1).

1: Docker's python wrapper: `docker-py`; not the real `docker` executable which is written in Go.

Note: There is a request to provide backward compatibility — not sure if it will be accepted. **Docker Compose v2 switch is totally worth, btw**. It is a clean implementation.

Credit: Tim Panohos's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77642303/452102) for the issue link.

Answer (score 4):

Found this article on Git: https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/3194#issuecomment-1848950456

I got it to work by reverting the suggested change in the utils.py i.e.
sudo nano ./usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/docker/utils/utils.py

Finding: def kwargs_from_env(environment=None):(See file docker/utils/utils.py line 344)

and adding: def kwargs_from_env(environment=None, ssl_version=None)

However, I think there is a reason for why its depreciated and probably due to encrytions have evolved - so I would try it get your project to run then revert  back...?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, everyone for the great ideas. This is how we've solved the problem:

As we did not want to downgrade to 6.1.3, we went and replaced `docker-compose` to `docker compose` cmd, but it failed to build as there was no supported argument '-f file.yml'.

it became clear that in GitLab CI/CD we were using image "docker:latest" which seems to have been built like 3 years ago and it supported docker client 18.smth

finally, we switched the image to `image: docker:20.10.24 services: - docker:20.10.24-dind` that we understood as the real latest stable version.

with the cleaning of some previous compatibility hacks it worked fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 and switchin from python2.7 to python 3.8. After googling, the fix is

```
sudo pip install --upgrade docker-py
```